# Java blackjack program

Tags: java, methods, numberformatexception

**So I rewrote it with your suggestion (Todd Hopp) and updated the post in the (*) section in the BlackJack class so you can see how I have it now but I'm still getting the same errors and it is not printing the computePlayerValue for some reason....**

---

ERROR: 
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input  string: "King"           at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

```
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at BlackJack.dealCards(BlackJack.java:25)
at PlayCardGame.main(PlayCardGame.java:9)
```

**P.S. I'm was trying to look this up in the book but couldn't find the answer...The BlackJack class is partially source code from an earlier chapter in the book and I couldn't figure out if it was necessary to have super(); in the constructor there?  I thought it only had to do if the parent class constructor had an argument?  Any help on if it has to be there and if so what it's doing.**

BlackJack Class

```
 public class BlackJack extends CardGameFP{
    int computePlayerValue;
    int computeDealerValue;
    int cardValue;

    public BlackJack() {
        **super();**
        player1 = 2;
        player2 = 2;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("BlackJack");
    }
//************************************************************* 
    public int getCardValue(Card card) {
    final String rank = card.getRank();
    switch (rank) {
        case "Ace":
            return 1;
        case "King":
        case "Queen":
        case "Jack":
            return 10;
        default:
            return Integer.parseInt(rank);
    }
}

public void dealCards() {
    //Player 1
    System.out.println("Player 1:");
    for(int x = 0; x < playerHand; x++) {
        shuffle();
        System.out.println(fullDeck[x].getRank() + " of " + fullDeck[x].getSuit());
    }
    cardValue1 = getCardValue(fullDeck[0]);
    cardValue2 = getCardValue(fullDeck[1]);
    computePlayerValue = cardValue1 + cardValue2;
    System.out.println(computePlayerValue);
}

//*************************************************************


        //Dealer hand
        System.out.println("\nPlayer 2:");
        for(int x = 0; x < player2; x++) {
            System.out.println(fullDeck[x].getRank() + " of " + fullDeck[x].getSuit() );
            shuffle();
        }
    }
    }


public class Card {

protected String suit;
protected int value;
protected String rank;
protected final int LOW_VALUE = 1;
protected final int HIGH_VALUE = 13;


public String getRank() {
    return rank;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public String getSuit() { 
    return suit;
}

public void setSuit(String st) {
    suit = st;
}

public void setValue(int val) {
    if(val >= LOW_VALUE && val <= HIGH_VALUE) {
        value = val;
    }
    else {
        value = LOW_VALUE;
    }
    if(val == 1) {
        rank = "Ace";
    }
    else if(val == 11) {
        rank = "Jack";
    }
    else if(val == 12) {
        rank = "Queen";
    }
    else if(val == 13) {
        rank = "King";
    }
    else {
        rank = Integer.toString(value);
    }           
}   
}
```

CardGame Class

```
abstract public class CardGameFP {

int suitNum = 1;
int val = 1;
int player1;
int player2;
protected final int DECK_OF_CARDS = 52;
Card fullDeck[] = new Card[DECK_OF_CARDS];
protected final int LOW_VALUE = 1;
protected final int HIGH_VALUE = 13;
protected final int HIGH_SUIT = 4;
protected final int CARDS_IN_SUIT = 13;

public abstract void display();
public abstract void dealCards();

public CardGameFP() {
    for(int i = 0; i < fullDeck.length; i++) {
        fullDeck[i] = new Card();
        if(suitNum == 1) {
            fullDeck[i].setSuit("Spades");
        }
        else if(suitNum == 2) {
            fullDeck[i].setSuit("Hearts");
        }
        else if(suitNum == 3) {
            fullDeck[i].setSuit("Diamonds");
        }
        else {
            fullDeck[i].setSuit("Clubs");
        }
        fullDeck[i].setValue(val);
        val++;
        if(val > HIGH_VALUE) {
            suitNum++;
            val = 1;
        }            
    }//end for
}   
public void shuffle() {
    for(int firstCard = 0; firstCard < DECK_OF_CARDS; firstCard++ ) {
        firstCard = ((int)(Math.random() * 500) % DECK_OF_CARDS);
        int secondCard = ((int)(Math.random() * 500) % DECK_OF_CARDS);
        Card temp = fullDeck[firstCard];
        fullDeck[firstCard] = fullDeck[secondCard];
        fullDeck[secondCard] = temp;
    }
}
}
```

PlayCardGame Class

```
PlayerCardGame

    public class PlayCardGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Card CG = new Card();
        BlackJack BJ = new BlackJack();

        BJ.display();
        BJ.dealCards();
    }
    }
```

Comment: where do you actually call `java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)` in `BlackJack.dealCards()`. The error says you do, I don't see it

Comment: Sorry I copy and pasted an earlier code.  I fixed it, it's in the ** part of BlackJack class.

Comment: So I rewrote it with your suggestion and updated the post in the ** section so you can see but I'm still getting the same errors and it is not printing the computePlayerValue for some reason.

Comment: You shouldn't change your original code to the point where the question no longer makes sense. Just add to the bottom so people can see how the problem is evolving without having to read the edit history.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't know you can do that. I thought I had to edit the post.  The only thing I see is add comment or answer question, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this line:

```
cardValue = Integer.parseInt(fullDeck[0].getRank());
```

I suggest that you create a `getCardValue(Card)` method:

```
public int getCardValue(Card card) {
    final String rank = card.getRank();
    switch (rank) {
        case "Ace":
            return 1;
        case "King":
        case "Queen":
        case "Jack":
            return 10;
        default:
            return Integer.parseInt(rank);
    }
}
```

and then use:

```
cardValue = getCardValue(fullDeck[0]);
```

EDIT: Following the suggestion by @WorldSEnder, you can define a `Rank` enum:

```
public enum Rank {
    ACE("Ace", 1),
    TWO("2", 2),
    ...
    QUEEN("Queen", 10),
    KING("King", 10);

    private final String displayName;
    private final int value;

    protected Rank(String displayName, int value) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String displayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public int value() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then you can modify `Card` to use a `Rank` instead of a `String` for the rank and use:

```
cardValue = fullDeck[0].getRank().value();
```

Comment: It would also be advisible to use an enum instead of a string for the rank (and suite)

Comment: @WorldSEnder - Yeah, I thought of suggesting that. The `enum` could also have a `getCardValue()` method that returned the appropriate value. However, you can't have an enum with a name of, say, "2", so it would also have to have a method to retrieve the display name.

Comment: I have to oppose the second thought. It is not really the enum's job to return the value. I would go as far as writing a `Hand` class, gathering the cards a player has and drop the `#getValue()` method into that

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try above.  This is kind of extra credit & I only have one day left its due tomorrow.  I didn't really want to rewrite the entire thing, I was just trying to give it some game play even if it's just one hand at a time.  Since the cards are already set up how they are I didn't really want to rewrite the entire thing.  I'm gonna post something I've been working on in the same starred section, take into account that I'll be using what you have above.  I'm not sure why computePlayerValue isn't printing though. I'm just trying to see if it's calculating correctly and nothing print

Comment: So I rewrote it with your suggestion and updated the post in the ** section so you can see but I'm still getting the same errors and it is not printing the computePlayerValue for some reason.

Comment: @user3862586 - If you're still getting a `NumberFormatException`, please try debugging and checking what string it is trying to parse.

Comment: Still the same, Ace, Jack, Queen and King.  Also, not sure if you saw my comment above but I apologize for changing the original post, how do I add at the bottom?  The only thing I thought you could do is add a comment or it says answer question...?

Comment: @user3862586 - If it's still trying to parse "Ace" as an integer value, then the `switch` isn't doing its job. Are you sure there aren't trailing spaces or some other characters in the rank strings? As for editing, just edit as usual, scroll to the bottom of your current post, and append new text there.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying.  I'll check out the switch and report back.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

When you call :

```
 cardValue = Integer.parseInt(fullDeck[0].getRank());
```

the method `Interger.parseInt()` is attempting to read an `int` from a `string`. The problem is that some cards have ranks which themselves are not strings like, `King`. So when you return the rank of that card, `parseInt()` doesn't know how to handle `King`. You should instead be getting the cards actual value using `fullDeck[0].getVaule()` and parsing that instead. It will be a string between 1 and 13.

Comment: Except in blackjack, all face cards have a hand value of 10.

Comment: Actually, depending on house rules, a King and an Ace will often score higher than a 10 and an Ace.

Comment: Ok I understand what's going on now.  I think I can work it out.  Thanks!

Comment: @Gnarlywhale - I never heard of such a variant. What do you mean "score higher"? As far as I know, a ten or any face card together with an Ace are worth 21, otherwise what you're playing isn't BlackJack.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what @Gnarlywhale was trying to say, but an Ace can count as either 1 or 11.

Comment: I was thinking of a variant of BlackJack, a card game called 21, in which we used the the face type of card to determine a winner in the case of a tie (i.e. a king and ace pair would defeat a queen and ace pair), which for granted is not casino BlackJack rules. I stand by this implementation however because user3862586's main assignment is to create a card dealing program, not blackjack, in which face cards having separate values (not all 10s) may be a requirement.